# 'K-means' cluster analysis

Tags: python, statistics, k-means

I want to get values ​​such as mean, min, max. std dev. for each group of clusters calculated using the k-means method. Is the code below correct?

```
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

    dataset = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/../cardio_train_py.csv", sep=';')    
    clusterDB_1 = dataset[['Age','BMI','cardio']].copy()
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=8).fit(clusterDB_1)
    
    X=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    print('Age mean() for each cluster')
    for x in X:
        check = clusterDB_1[kmeans.labels_ == x]
        print(check['Age'].mean())
    print('BMI mean() for each cluster')
    for x in X:
        check = clusterDB_1[kmeans.labels_ == x]
        print(check['BMI'].mean())
    print('cardio == 0 count() for each cluster')
    
    for x in X:
        check = clusterDB_1[kmeans.labels_ == x]
        print(len(check[check['cardio'] == 1]))
```

I'm asking because the obtained values ​​(e.g. mean for Age and BMI and cardio count == 0) is different than values obtained in Statistica(the photo shows the results of the program [Statistica results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKvxd.jpg))
Below is the result of BMI (Python calculation)

```
24.468587736260996
24.047855933307282
30.548865468674116
31.98410463004993
32.89129084635681
166.57357142857146
41.97845737483085
24.16813400017246
```

here is my database => https://www.easypaste.org/file/JcyGhA8Y/cardio.train.py.csv?lang=pl

Thanks for all help and tips :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do just what you want, in one line:

```
clusterDB_1.groupby(kmeans.labels_).mean()
```

Comment: Is there a way for python to know that cardio is a categorical variable?

Comment: No. You will have to exclude it from the range of columns.

Comment: Is there any library that can deal with this problem?